# How does one inspect X509 public key certificates from the command line in bash or unix

Tags: bash, command-line, certificate, x509certificate, pki

X509 public key certificates are pretty cryptic when you look at them with a normal editor. Are there any unix standard command line tools that allow one to view a X509 certificates or at least list and selectively extract their fields??? If there are not how would one go about doing this another way?

Comment: Could the person how down-voted my question please provide some CONSTRUCTIVE feedback on so that I can edit it. Please.

Comment: I am certainly not intending to start a politicised debate about which tool is better than the other. Any tool that obeys the RFCs will produce the same output regardless.If you look at an X509 certificate in a text editor such as vim the contents will be unintelligible and bear little obvious resemblance to the RFCs. I am simply asking is there a standard unix or bash utility that allows someone to extract the values of fields defined in these RFCs. I am only trying to examine certificates and extract useful information from them without writing my own program to do so as I have limited time.

Answer (score 8):

openssl x509 -in $CERTIFICATE_FILE -text

(One may have to add the -inform parameter if the certificate is not in PEM format)

Output looks exactly like the RFCs' description:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=765d52947c71fdd569321f117d5b3ea2618f41b9
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep 10 13:22:53 2013 GMT
            Not After : Jul  1 00:00:00 2014 GMT
        Subject: CN=ef2dea1c4e2d54acbe102b7b8c3bd4f542cda72c
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus (2048 bit):
                    00:94:c8:0e:72:f8:63:f5:be:aa:6d:79:91:3b:f0:
                    bf:06:68:7e:c1:bc:f1:f
```

..etc etc

Comment: And if the certificate is in a JKS or PKCS12 keystore, you can use the Java `keytool` command to view the contents: `keytool -list -v -storetype PKCS12 -keystore $KEYSTORE_FILE`.  If it's a JKS keystore, the `storetype` parameter is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: `-noout` to not output the content of the certificate